# How to deal with intentionally undefined variables in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a view in Laravel that I use for both inserting records and updating records. When it comes to a checkbox, I use the following code:

```
      {!! Form::checkbox('active', 1, $info->active) !!}
```

`$info` refers to the retrieved record from a database passed to the view from the controller (I do something like `$info = MyModel::findOrFail($id)`), which clearly only applies when I edit the record. When I create a new record this variable does not exist and I get this error:

`Undefined variable`

That makes total sense, but the question is: what is the best way to go around this. Should I use a conditional statement? Should I create an empty variable? Should I use two different checkboxes? What is recommended here?

Comment: Why not simply check for the variable with isset?

Comment: Yes that is one of the options. But is that the recommended way? And where would I do that? I don't seem to be able to do that inside this function so it needs to be something around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set `$info = new MyModel()` for the create form.

It makes sense conceptually, keeps your templates clean, and avoids duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use two separate views for both insertion and deletion. That's why route resources have methods like index, create, , store, show, edit, update, delete etc.

In your case, I would suggest you to use two views and follow the convention over configuration principle:

```
public function create()
{
  return view('post.create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
  $post = Post::create($request->all());
}

public function edit()
{
  return view('post.edit');
}

public function update($id, Request $request)
{
  $post = Post::whereId($id)->update($request->all());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like the following when creating:

```
// Controller.
$user = new User;

// View
Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.store', $user]])
```

I have used this approach before to address exactly your issue.